# JqGrid: Showing text for HTML elements inside column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

I have used gridComplete to show HTML buttons but it shows the HTML text instead of button and encoded HTML as title which does not look good. Kindly help me remove or change the title (tooltip) and show the buttons

**The Output**

[image: The output -]

When I inspect this cell then I could see the following in chrome tools -

```
<td role="gridcell" style="" title="&amp;lt;input type='button' value='Publish' onclick='publish(100)' /&amp;gt;" aria-describedby="list_actionBtn">&lt;input type='button' value='Publish' onclick='publish(100)' /&gt;</td>
```

**The jqgrid Code**

```
var myColModel = [ {
    name : "promoId",
    index : 'Promotionid',
    width : 60
}, {
    name : "promoCode",
    index : 'promotioncode',
    width : 110
}, {
    name : "name",
    index : 'name',
    width : 160
}, {
    name : "description",
    index : 'description',
    width : 250
}, {
    name : "distCode",
    index : 'distributor_code',
    width : 110
} , {
    name : "statusId",
    hidden : true
} , {
    name : "statusVal",
    index : 'status',
    width : 90
}, {
    name : "startDate",
    index : 'start_date',
    width : 100,
    sorttype : "date",
    align : "right"
}, {
    name : "endDate",
    index : 'end_date',
    width : 100,
    sorttype : "date",
    align : "right"
}, {
    name : "discount",
    index : 'discount',
    width : 80
}, {
    name : "extension",
    index : 'extension',
    width : 80
}, {
    name : "isDiscount",
    hidden : true
}, {
    name : "isExtension",
    hidden : true
}, {
    name : "actionBtn",
    width : 100
} ];
$(function() {
    $("#list")
            .jqGrid(
                    {
                        url : '/suiactcodegen/action/promotion/promolist',
                        datatype : "json",
                        mtype : "GET",
                        colNames : [ "Promo ID", "Promo Code", "Name",
                                "Description", "Distributor Code", "Stt Id",
                                "Status", "Start Date", "End Date",
                                "Discount", "Extension", "Is Disc", "isExtn", "" ],
                        colModel : myColModel,
                        pager : "#pager",
                        rowNum : 10,
                        rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
                        sortname : "end_date",
                        sortorder : "asc",
                        viewrecords : true,
                        gridview : true,
                        rownumber : true,
                        autoencode : true,
                        width : '1000px',
                        height : 'auto',
                        caption : "Promotion Summary",
                        gridComplete: function() {
                            var ids = $("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
                            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                                var rowId = ids[i],
                                    statusId = $("#list").jqGrid ('getCell', rowId, 'statusId'),
                                    activeBtn = "";
                                    if (statusId == 0) { // Inactive
                                        activeBtn = "<input type='button' value='Publish' " +
                                           "onclick='publish(" + rowId + ")' />";
                                    }
                                    //else if (statusId == 1) { // Published
                                    //  activeBtn = "<input type='button' value='Expire' " +
                                    //       "onclick=\"expire(" + rowId + ");\" />";
                                    //} 
                                 $("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', rowId, { actionBtn: activeBtn });
                            }
                        } 
                        }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', {
                add : false,
                edit : false,
                del : false,
                search : true,
                refresh : false
            }).jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', {
                caption : " Edit ",
                // buttonicon: "ui-icon-bookmark",
                onClickButton : editPromo,
                position : "last"
            });


});
```

**-- Update --**
I have already tried autoencode = false for this column but it didn't work

**IMP Update**
The reason why it doesn't work I believe is because datatype is 'json' but button type is not json data type. How can I create it as a separate row? In case of 'local' data it works. See the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zpXCT/3/. Even tested it in my localhost

Comment: What version of jqGrid are you using?

Comment: Justin, 4.3.2 version of jqGrid and jQuery 1.6.1

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: @Salman, I created a sample fiddle with similar case except that the data is local and it works fine. But I am using server data and can't create a fiddle with server data. Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/zpXCT/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sry I copied the basic grid from JqGrid site and then edited that and didn't notice that autoencode:true for grid level. So even though I mentioned it for column level it wasn't working. Now it appears.

Answer (score 1):

Set colmodel datatype = 'html'