# jqGrid add buttons ti each row

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid I want to add button to jqGrid I have reffered [jqGridDemo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html) and did the same but instead of showing button it is showing me the string value for be

My sample code is

```
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid({
    url:'server.php?q=3',
    datatype: "json",
    colNames:['Buttons','type','school'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'act',index:'act', width:75,sortable:false},
        {name:'type',index:'type', width:55},
        {name:'school',index:'school', width:90, editable:true}],
    rowNum:10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    pager: '#prowed2',
    sortname: 'id',
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    gridComplete: function(){
        var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){
            var cl = ids[i];
            be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editRow('"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
            se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\"  />"; 
            ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
            jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{act:be+se+ce});
        }   
    }

});
jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('navGrid',"#prowed2",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

I am getting result as [image]

Where am I lacking?

Comment: set autoencode:false `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010021/jqgrid-showing-text-for-html-elements-inside-column